# retrieve distinct field value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

What is the most efficient way to retrieve distinct column values. I have a table with fields `FormsID` and `ProductLineDescription` along with other columns. `ProductLine` table has a one to many relationship, the sample data in the table would be like:

```
FormID ProdculineDesc
1      abc
2      abc
1      xyz
2      def
3      abc
3      xyz
```

I want the dropdown to have just the distinct values of `ProductLineDesc`. Here is the code,

```
private void LoadProductLines(Models.SearchModel Model, xyzEntities Context)
{
    Model.ProductLine = Context.PRODUCTLINEs
        .OrderBy(T => T.FormsGuid).ToSelectList().Distinct();
}
```

This still gives me every `ProductLineDesc`, how do I retrieve just the `Distinct` values.

Comment: You can either `.GroupBy` and use `ProductLineDesc` as the grouping column or perform a `.Select` on that column first then use `.Distinct`. You can also create your own [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and keep the objects as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with a custom quality comparer (with [example](http://ideone.com/Vxw8q)):

```
public class UniqueProductLineDesc : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public Boolean Equals(Product a, Product b)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return false;

        return String.Compare(a.ProductLineDesc, b.ProductLineDesc, true) == 0;
    }

    public Int32 GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null))
            return 0;

        return product.ProductLineDesc == null ? 0 : product.ProductLineDesc.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And to implement:

```
private void LoadProductLines(Models.SearchModel Model, xyzEntities Context)
{
    Model.ProductLine = Context.PRODUCTLINEs
        .OrderBy(T => T.FormsGuid)
        .ToSelectList()
        .Distinct(new UniqueProductLineDesc());
}
```

Comment: is there a much simpler way? I'm sure this will work, but is there something simpler, by just mentioning the Distinct with the field that I want unique?

Comment: Adding a class to do the distinct check isn't _simple_?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var distinctInfo = (from c in Context.PRODUCTLINEs
                           group by c.ProductLineDesc into result
    select new Model.ProductLine {
    ProductLineDesc = result.Key,
    FormID = result.Min(d=>d.FormID)
    });
```